# How to scrape text from different classes within 'td' in BS4?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I want to scrape the table from this website: [NCLT](https://archive.nclt.gov.in/judgement-date-wise?field_bench_target_id=5372&field_search_date_value%5Bmin%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/19&field_search_date_value%5Bmax%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/21&page=0)

I want to take this table's data in the same format including the hyperlinks and put it into an excel worksheet. I have already tried copy pasting the table but the formatting of table messes up. I want my data in a Dataframe in CSV format or Excel format.

Here's what I've tried:

```
url = "https://archive.nclt.gov.in/judgement-date-wise?field_bench_target_id=5372&field_search_date_value%5Bmin%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/19&field_search_date_value%5Bmax%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/21&page=0"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
```

**part where I am facing problem.**

```
    t_r= soup.find_all('tr')
t_r[1]
```

**gives following output:**

```
<tr class="odd views-row-first">
<td class="views-field views-field-counter">
            1          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-field-cp-no">
            CPNo.464/BB/2018          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-field-name-of-petitioner">
            M/s Shankar Subramanya bhat Vs M/s Star Cable Infomet Pvt Ltd
<br/>
A Murali,  Advocate 
<br/>
SPJ Legal R1-4          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-field-final-order-date">
<span class="date-display-single" content="2020-01-16T00:00:00+05:30" datatype="xsd:dateTime" property="dc:date">16-01-2020</span> </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-field-final-orders-pdf">
<a href="https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Star%20Cable.pdf" target="_blank"><img alt="PDF icon" class="file-icon" src="modules/file/icons/application-pdf.png" title="application/pdf"/></a> Size :- 6.5 MB, Language:- English          </td>
</tr>
```

Since I am new to BS4 I am trying to figure out on how to copy the Following from each t_r[i]:

So far in my code i am only able to gather S.no. using the following snippet:

```
t_r[1].td.string.replace('\n', '').strip()
```

I also want a similar code to obtain: `CPNo.464/BB/2018`  ,  `M/s Shankar Subramanya bhat Vs M/s Star Cable Infomet Pvt Ltd`, `16-01-2020`, `https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Star%20Cable.pdf"`

For some reason, I am not being able to the same for the rest of the fields in `t_r[i]`. I don't understand how to progress further than this. I want extract the rest of the data as well but using the '`t_r.contents`' isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**How I want the output to look like**
[This output but with just the href link in the last column instead of size and medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haiC7.png)

Answer (score 1):

To get the table + PDF Links you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://archive.nclt.gov.in/judgement-date-wise?field_bench_target_id=5372&field_search_date_value%5Bmin%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/19&field_search_date_value%5Bmax%5D%5Bdate%5D=01/01/21&page=0"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select_one("table.views-table")
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
# get pdf links:
df["PDF File"] = [
    a["href"] for a in soup.select("td.views-field-field-final-orders-pdf a")
]

print(df)
```

Prints:

|  | S. No | Diary No. / Case No.[STATUS] | Name of Petitioner | Judgement date | PDF File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | CPNo.464/BB/2018 | M/s Shankar Subramanya bhat Vs M/s Star Cable Infomet Pvt Ltd A Murali, Advocate SPJ Legal R1-4 | 16-01-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Star%20Cable.pdf |
| 1 | 2 | CA(CAA)No.50/BB/2020 | E2open Software India Pvt Ltd Vs Shyam Sundar H V, Adv Respondent Advocate : -- | 16-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/E2OPen.pdf |
| 2 | 3 | CA(CAA)No.51/BB/2020 | Amber Road Software Pvt Ltd Vs Shyam Sundar H V, Adv Respondent Advocate : -- | 16-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Amber%20Road.pdf |
| 3 | 4 | CA(CAA)No.48/BB/2020 | Steelwedge Technologies Pvt Ltd Vs Shyam Sundar H V, Adv Respondent Advocate : -- | 16-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Steelwedge.pdf |
| 4 | 5 | CPNo.158/BB/2020 | Marble Industry [Mangalore] Pvt Ltd & Others Vs ROC Chethan Jeevandas Nayak, PCS Respondent Advocate : -- | 16-10-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/cp%20no%20158%20of%202020.pdf |
| 5 | 6 | CP(IB)No.156/BB/2017 | Triumph India Software Services Pvt Ltd Vs Corporation Bank Girish Kumar M.S Shri Venkata Subbarao Kalva Liquidator, Vivekananda for Liquidator | 04-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Triumph%20India%20Software%20Services%20Pvt%20Ltd%20Vs%20Corporation%20Bank.pdf |
| 6 | 7 | CPNo.129/BB/2020 | M/s Shamel Projects India Pvt Ltd Vs Arjun Amanchi, Advocate Respondent Advocate : -- | 11-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/NCLT20210119111719.pdf |
| 7 | 8 | CP(IB)No.263/BB/2019 | M/s RDC Concrete (India) Pvt Ltd Vs M/s Sukritha Buildmann Pvt Ltd Ricab Chad, Advocate Abhijit Atur, Advocate | 25-10-2019 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/Ms%20%20RDC%20Concrete%20%28India%29%20Pvt%20Ltd%20%20VS%20Ms%20Sukritha%20Buildmann%20Pvt%20Ltd%20_0.pdf |
| 8 | 9 | CP(IB)No.214/BB/2020 | Shapoorji Pallonji and Company Pvt Ltd Vs Shore Dwellings Pvt Ltd[formerly known as Mantri Dwellings Pvt Ltd] Keystone Partners Respondent Advocate : -- | 18-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/CP%20IB%20214%20of%202020.pdf |
| 9 | 10 | CPNo.193/BB/2020 | Chiteta Mining Company Pvt Ltd Vs Jose Thomas, PCS Respondent Advocate : -- | 30-12-2020 | https://archive.nclt.gov.in/sites/default/files/January2021/final-orders-pdf/NCLT20210111165206.pdf |

Comment: I want to scrape the whole 137 pages on the website. I have created a loop with the web address that extracts table from each page with your help. But I want to put it all into one final df. How can I do that? My code is giving output of last page's table only.

Comment: @simrpal at the start make an empty list `dfs=[]`. In the loop add each dataframe to this list. At the end of program use `final_df = pd.concat(dfs)` to make one big dataframe.